# Translating a text from the XV century to modern Spanish

Tags: historia

### Important update:

I am moving the problem of translating this document to [this other thread](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/researching-a-spanish-document-from-the-xv-century), which is the original thread that was asked in the [History SE site](https://history.stackexchange.com/) and has now been migrated to [Spanish Language and Usage SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/). This thread can be safely closed. Thanks!

### Original question:

I am trying to translate the following text written in old Spanish to modern Spanish (see [this thread](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6259/researching-a-spanish-document-from-the-xv-century#comment11674_6259) for more information on the nature of this document):

[image]

I think I have almost everything translated but there are three words that I still don't know what they mean (see them in bold):

> Por estas preguntas se examinan los testigos en la **__provança__** que hacen Juan Núñez y Alonso Núñez Salgero:
>
> Primera:
>
> Si conocen a los dichos Juan Núñez y a Alson Núñez Salgero, que el **__dho__** Juan Núñez fuera de veinte y un años, mediano de cuerpo y una
>   señal de quemadura en la cabeza. Y el dicho Alonso Núñez de diez y
>   ocho años poco mas o menos, alto de cuerpo que le apunta el boco , de
>   color rojo, y cuello negro.  Y si conocen a los **__dhos__.**, **__Su__** Nuñez
>   Salgero y Mayor de Vilches, su mujer, sus padres y conocen y
>   conocieron, a Alóso"..

Also, if you happen to have read the [original thread](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6259/researching-a-spanish-document-from-the-xv-century#comment11674_6259), but do you think is the purpose of this document? What type of exam is this? I know it's hard without more information, but unfortunately this is all I have for the moment :/.

Comment: Could *dho* and *dhos* refer to *dicho* and *dichos*? And I guess what you understood as ***_Su_*** is actually *Juan*. As for *provança*, I have no idea...

Comment: See this [meta post](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/282/12) relating to this question.

Comment: Note thatit is not "fuera" but rather "será" shortly after Juan Núnez, and the penultimate word is not Alóso but Alõso.  The tilde was an abbreviation for a subsequent _n_ so you'd interpret it as _Alonso_.  The squiggle about the _e_ in the final word is likewise an abbreviation for _z_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text seems to be a judicial/police *probe* (official investigation) about as I read in the original thread seems to be if they are of *pure blood* (not from muslim or jew descents). Actually, that is what "*[provança](http://www.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=dlDTXtRM2DXX2FxohzA8)*" seems to mean, which nowadays is "**probanza**":

> (De probar).
>
> 1. f. Averiguación o prueba que jurídicamente se hace de algo.

"*Dho*" apparently is an abbreviation of "dicho" used by [clerks/copyists at the time](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?pid=S1668-81042001000100007&script=sci_arttext):

> Previo a la consideración de la evolución de las abreviaturas en el
>   español del Jujuy colonial, observaremos varias abreviaturas que se
>   reiteran en dos o más testamentos con idéntico procedimiento:
>
> > ...
> >      dicha = dha.
> >      dicho = dho.
> >      ...